# CSS3 Animation only renders one frame

Tags: html, css, animation, webkit

i am trying to animate the background of some text (here icons).
I set the background to an gradient and then apply transperancy to the text.
After that it shows me just the gradient as background. It stays on the initial frame and does not change. Can you maybe tell me why it does not animate?

```
section.features .feature-item i {
    font-size: 80px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;

    background: linear-gradient(253deg, #ff002b, #00fff6, #07ffb4, #4307ff, #ff00df);
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;

       background-size: 1000% 1000%;

       -webkit-animation: iconBG 3s ease infinite;
       -moz-animation: iconBG 3s ease infinite;
       -o-animation: iconBG 3s ease infinite;
       animation: iconBG 3s ease infinite;

       @-webkit-keyframes iconBG {
           0%{background-position:0% 99%}
           50%{background-position:100% 2%}
           100%{background-position:0% 99%}
       }
       @-moz-keyframes iconBG {
           0%{background-position:0% 99%}
           50%{background-position:100% 2%}
           100%{background-position:0% 99%}
       }
       @-o-keyframes iconBG {
           0%{background-position:0% 99%}
           50%{background-position:100% 2%}
           100%{background-position:0% 99%}
       }
       @keyframes iconBG {
           0%{background-position:0% 99%}
           50%{background-position:100% 2%}
           100%{background-position:0% 99%}
       }

  }
```

It just freezes on the frame you can see in the image. Gradient does not change at all[image: ![Gradient background]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR9P5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your code, there's just wrong with the end of the "section.features .feature-item i" you can't end it with the animation code

```
section.features .feature-item i  {
    font-size: 80px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;

    background: linear-gradient(253deg, #ff002b, #00fff6, #07ffb4, #4307ff, #ff00df);
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;

       background-size: 1000% 1000%;

       -webkit-animation: iconBG 3s ease infinite;
       -moz-animation: iconBG 3s ease infinite;
       -o-animation: iconBG 3s ease infinite;
       animation: iconBG 3s ease infinite;
}
       @-webkit-keyframes iconBG {
           0%{background-position:0% 99%}
           50%{background-position:100% 2%}
           100%{background-position:0% 99%}
       }
       @-moz-keyframes iconBG {
           0%{background-position:0% 99%}
           50%{background-position:100% 2%}
           100%{background-position:0% 99%}
       }
       @-o-keyframes iconBG {
           0%{background-position:0% 99%}
           50%{background-position:100% 2%}
           100%{background-position:0% 99%}
       }
       @keyframes iconBG {
           0%{background-position:0% 99%}
           50%{background-position:100% 2%}
           100%{background-position:0% 99%}
       }
```

Comment: You're Welcome, here's the JSfiddle by the way if you need it in the future: https://jsfiddle.net/Liamm12/b40b0rdy/

Answer (score 1):

You have your keyframes inside the class selector. Try taking them outside the selector, and you should get your animation

```
   @-webkit-keyframes iconBG {
       0%{background-position:0% 99%}
       50%{background-position:100% 2%}
       100%{background-position:0% 99%}
   }
   @-moz-keyframes iconBG {
       0%{background-position:0% 99%}
       50%{background-position:100% 2%}
       100%{background-position:0% 99%}
   }
   @-o-keyframes iconBG {
       0%{background-position:0% 99%}
       50%{background-position:100% 2%}
       100%{background-position:0% 99%}
   }
   @keyframes iconBG {
       0%{background-position:0% 99%}
       50%{background-position:100% 2%}
       100%{background-position:0% 99%}
   }

section.features .feature-item i {
    font-size: 80px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;

    background: linear-gradient(253deg, #ff002b, #00fff6, #07ffb4, #4307ff,    #ff00df);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;

   background-size: 1000% 1000%;

   -webkit-animation: iconBG 3s ease infinite;
   -moz-animation: iconBG 3s ease infinite;
   -o-animation: iconBG 3s ease infinite;
   animation: iconBG 3s ease infinite;
```

}